# Javascript set maxlength based on newly created dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a javascript that dynamically can create dropdownlists and textboxes. And whenever you select a new value from the dropdownlist a maximumlength for the textbox is looked up using the code behind.

But I need to set a maxlength in the textbox if the first value in the dropdownlist is used.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e) { //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if (x <= max_fields) { //max input box allowed
            var dv = $('<div/>'),
                select = $('<select name="DynamicDropDown' + x + '" id=' + x + ' onChange="changeMaxLength(this.id)" />').appendTo(dv);
            var selectedid = $('<select name="DynamicDropDown" />').id;
            dv.append('&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" size="25" style="margin-right:20px" name="DynamicTextBox' + x + '" />&nbsp;<a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a>');
            $(wrapper).append(dv);
            getCars(select);
            x++; //text box increment
        }
        select.fireEvent("onChange");
        var temp = document.getElementById('1');
        temp.changeMaxLength(00);

    });

    $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('div').remove();
        x--;
    })
});
```

'changeMaxLength' returns the maximum length for the selected dropdown value.

I have tried:

```
select.fireEvent("onChange");
                var temp = document.getElementById('1');
                temp.changeMaxLength(00);
```

How do I set a maxlength on the first textbox based on the first value in the dropdownlist?

Comment: Can you please provide the HTML

Answer (score 0):

You can set the max length of the textbox using maxlength property

You can add using javascript

`$("#textbox").attr("maxlength", 25);`

or add as attribute in input html tag

`<input type="text" name="" maxlength="25">`